# Android ViewPager can not load 3rd Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have encourage with the problem when i load 3 Fragments into ViewPager
Each time i started the Activity, there are just only 2 fragments (Fragment 1 & Fragment 2) is loaded.
I dont know why the Fragment 3 is not been load.

Below is my code

Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_testing);
        // load pager data
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerTestingRegister);
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(new Fragment1());
        fragments.add(new Fragment2());
        fragments.add(new Fragment3());

        viewPager.setAdapter(new RegisterTestingFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments));
```

}

Activity UI

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/expense1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Expense1">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollTabHost"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"></TabWidget>
        </HorizontalScrollView>



        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:persistentDrawingCache="all"
                android:id="@+id/pagerTestingRegister">
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Adapter

```
public class RegisterTestingFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
List<Fragment> fragments;

public RegisterTestingFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Fragment> fragments){
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

public RegisterTestingFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(fragmentManager);
    //this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}
```

}

Comment: can u post the fragment 3 code and also check the log inside getCount() method and print fragments.size()

Comment: and one more thing... does 3 pages are created and 3rd page is showing blank or only 2 pages are created inside viewpager?

Comment: @AngadTiwari, The Fragment 3  will be loaded/created after i scroll ViewPager to page 2 or page 3. When Activity create it was not loaded/created
fragments.size() value is always 3

Comment: so, you want to load all 3 fragment at each call of onCreate() (means at every time activity created) ?

Comment: Yes, That is what i needed. Can ViewPage load one by one? 
- oncreated() loads 1
- change page 1 loads 2
- change page 2 loads 3

Comment: yes this is default property of viewpager...at page 1 -page2 is loaded...and  at page 2, it persist the state of page3 and page 1...you can try viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Comment: @Angad 1 is the default, maybe you meant 0.

Comment: no you can't set 0... min and default is 1

Comment: mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); put this line after viewpager initialize it should work

Answer (score 4):

this works for me:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

as mentioned by [Angad Tiwari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4013828/angad-tiwari) in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051682/android-viewpager-can-not-load-3rd-fragment/43469982#comment53924865_33051682)